# how to implement a custom OAuth provider using Scribe

Tags: java, scala, oauth, oauth-2.0, scribe

Is is possible to implement a OAuth provider using Scribe.
If so is that mentioned anywhere in the documentation.
I have seen in the github site most of them seems to be the clients.